# Android animation not working on isShown method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

i have a animation not working which should be triggered on a button click, the click checks if the image is shown and runs a animation if so, then in the else runs a different animation. problem is only the animation in the else statement is working. the if statement is still carried out if conditions are metm tested with logcat, the animation just does not happen. any help appreciated.

following being called on a click event

```
  if (smsArea.isShown()) {
                Animation backDoww = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                        R.anim.slide_out_right);
                smsArea.startAnimation(slide_out_right);
                smsArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                Animation slide_in_right= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                        R.anim.slide_in_right);
                smsArea.startAnimation(slide_in_right);
                smsArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

The animation in my else statement is the only one that works, the first animation that should be triggered with the if(smsArea.isShown()) never occurs.

i'm setting the smsArea to Gone initially, i'm doing this in the onCreate not in the xml, its left as its default viable in xml. i know the error is not in my animation file as even if i use the xml file in the else which i know works the animation does not happen.

XML

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/smsArea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"> .....   </LinearLayout>
```

Animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<translate android:duration="300" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
<alpha android:duration="300" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add animation listener:

```
backDoww.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
           smsArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

in onAnimationEnd hide your view.